# No Post matches the given query, allowing users to make post(django)

Tags: django

I'm trying to allow users to create category and post(that will be tagged to some category) I think I wrote the code right, but I'm getting 404 error with No Post matches the given query.
Here is my code.

```
this is my form
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="aa")
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields =('name',)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="bb")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'image', 'views', 'category']
```

this is my view

```
 #for adding category
    def add_category(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CategoryForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return index(request)
            else:
                print form.errors
        else:
            form = CategoryForm()

        return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})

    #for adding post/see diff style :)
    def add_post(request):
        context = RequestContext(request)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return redirect(index)
            else:
                print form.errors
        else:
            form = PostForm()
        return render_to_response('main/add_post.html', {'form':form}, context)
```

And this is my url

```
url(r'^add_post/', views.add_post, name='add_post'),
url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
```

]

And finally my templates
{

```
% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/main/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form}}

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Post">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `action="{% url 'main:add_post' %}"` instead of `action="/main/add_post/"`.
Also check that in your projects's urls.py main app's urls included with namespace like

```
url(r'^main/', include('main.urls', namespace="main"))
```

If you don't use namespace, than change to `action="{% url 'add_post' %}"`. 
If error reoccurs, please provide more information. 
Which ulr exactly you enter in browser to get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your template makes the form post to `main/add_post/` while your url for the view is `add_post/`. You should make them consistent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you are saying. so I should change what?

Comment: You should change this `url(r'^add_post/', views.add_post, name='add_post')` to `url(r'^main/add_post/$', views.add_post, name='add_post')`

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help but no that's not it, I'm using Django.